# which one sounds more natural? help me

Tags: modal-verbs

I know my dream is absurd and that I must face reality. So, I'm studying English now like this. However, I can still imagine me singing and dancing on a stage.

I know my dream is absurd and that I must face reality. So, I'm studying English now like this. However, I still imagine me singing and dancing on a stage.

I mean, "I can still imagine" vs "I still imagine"

Comment: Both sound OK: it depends what you want to say... to emphasize **can** imagine or **do** imagine... possibility, rather than actuality.

Comment: Note that the first sentence contains parallel clauses. The parallel clauses should be the same. There are three possibilities: Use no **that**s, use two **that**s, or have just one **that** in the first position, so that it's not part of the parallel clauses. One that in just the second parallel clause is inelegant. You start sentences 2 and 3, with conjunctions. That's OK if it helps to flow of the sentences, but this doesn't. It's like.... leaving.... gaps in ... a sentence. Eliminate **So** from the first sentence because it doesn't add anything, and put a comma before however.

Comment: You should fix "me" in the last sentence to "myself" as well.